# Invoke a Web Application via a shell script (or Tivoli Workload Scheduler - TWS)

Tags: shell, aix

I have a web application that performs a file download from a web site.

This needs to be performed at a regular intervals (once a week). I want to make a HTTP get request to this Web application so that it performs this job.

I can use the cron and a shell script.

This is on an IBM AIX machine. It does not have the ones like WGET, CURL etc that are availble in LINUXes to make a web request from the shell scripts directly.

The team here uses a Tivoli Workload Scheduler. I have very minimal skills in TWS so i don't know if there are options to make a HTTP request as part of a TWS job

Appreciate if someone could highlight options for achieving this on an AIX box. These machines are OS hardened so they would not allow me to download and compile utilities like WGET. I am forced to work with what is typically installed on an AIX box.

Thanks

Manglu

Comment: as a side note, TWS stands for Tivoli _Workload_ Scheduler (not Web)

Comment: Hi Snaguber, You are absolutely correct about the expansion for TWS.Apologies for the incorrect expansion in my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM host a number of Linux utilities which are compiled specifically for AIX.  So you can use wget.

[AIX Linux Toolbox](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/date.html)

Don't worry about it saying AIX 5.1, it's binary compatible with later releases.

If you can't use that (and encourage them to let you, we have it installed on plenty of production boxes, it's an official IBM AIX binary), then you'll need to write something in perl or similar, but if you want to use libraries to make it easier you'll need to download and install them ...

TWS doesn't have any functionality built in for that - it's purely an enterprise scale scheduler which runs other programs.